# MongoDB search start of field using regex

Tags: regex, mongodb, meteor

I have tried a few things to get this working but it always fails. I have a working regex query on a field however want I am trying to achieve is searching on the start of the string. i.e. if you search edi you would get Edinburgh.

I have the following regex query

```
Locations.find({name : { $regex: location + ".*", $options: 'ix'}}).fetch()
```

I read about using option m and ^ but it failed to retrieve any results.

Comment: location - what is it?

Comment: Are you using mongo shell? If yes i don`t know method fetch

Comment: This is meteor. Fetch returns pretty. Locations is the collection. The above works but doesn't give me the correct result. The question regarding the query.

Comment: "Locations is the collection." I mean what do you have in location variable when you put it into query?

Comment: Just tried to make a query in mongo shell like this > db.collection.find({'n' : {$regex : /^Bar.*/, $options : 'ix'}}).pretty(), query return correct data

Comment: A string. So as in the example. "edi"

Comment: hm, maybe this is cause you have extra brace in query at the end if it?

Comment: Try to change {name : { $regex: location + ".*", $options: 'ix'}}} to {name : { $regex: location + ".*", $options: 'ix'}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the regex pattern from your location variable, construct a new RegExp object
for e.g this match against all the names starting with location value ,case insensitive match

```
Locations.find({name : new RegExp('^'+location+'.*', "i")}).fetch()
```

However case insensitive regex is not index efficient "$regex can only use an index efficiently when the regular expression has an anchor for the beginning (i.e. ^) of a string and is a case sensitive match